# VS2013 Team Explorer - My Work, Results from query showing in "Available Work Items" differes from the results when query opened directly

Tags: visual-studio-2013, workitem, team-explorer

I'm a bit confused, why i don't get the same results with one query which is opened directly and which is then on the other hand showing different results if i choose the "Available Work Items" list in "Team Explorer - My Work".

You can see a query "KV.net2 2015.2" in below picture.
The query itself gives 5 results but "Available Work Items" only has 3 results.

May anyone have an idea about this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Available Work Items shows the first N items. If you click on "View All" it runs the query and you will see all 5 items.